# Compactly supported functions are dense in local Sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. I would like to know why $\mathcal{D}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}^l)=C^{\infty}_{\mathrm{c}}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}^l)$ is dense in $H^s_{\mathrm{loc}}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}^l)$ for all $s\in\mathbb{R}$. Is it true that it is also dense in $H^s_{\mathrm{c}}(\Omega,\mathbb{C}^l)$?

Comment: For $U$ convex containing $0$ and $f \in H^s(U)$ then $f(\frac{x}{1-\epsilon})$ is $H^s$ on a slightly larger open set so you can take the convolution with a mollifier. Then you can say $\Omega= \bigcup U_j$, using approximate identifies for the $U_j$, it should do it for $H^s_{loc}(\Omega)$

Comment: @reuns Sorry for a really late reply, was quite busy lately. I am new to these things, so my objection may be naive. But it seems to me that your approach might work only for $s\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ and I would really like to have a solution for a general real value. If I miss something, could elaborate on your solution, please?